# Google App Script onChnge trigger based on a spreadsheet i changed via GAS

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I have a script to send emails when a new row of data is added to the spreadsheet in question:

```
    const logTrigger = ()=>{
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendNow')
        .forSpreadsheet('SPREADSHEET_ID')
        .onChange()
        .create();
    }

    function sendNow() {
      let ssSendNow=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID').getActiveSheet();
      let ssLastRow = ssSendNow.getLastRow();

      let recipient = ssSendNow.getRange(ssLastRow,2).getValue();
      let subject = ssSendNow.getRange(ssLastRow,3).getValue();
      let body = ssSendNow.getRange(ssLastRow,4).getValue();

      const message = {
        to: recipient,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody:`${body}`,
        name:'BEA',
        noReply: true
      };
      MailApp.sendEmail(message);
    }
```

Each row is updated based on a separate Google App Script using `ss.getRange().setValues()`

Now, if I manually add in a row of data the script runs. But setting the values via Google App Script doesn't trigger the trigger. Is there anything I can do here?

Comment: About `But setting the values via Google App Script doesn't trigger the trigger.`, in this case, how about calling the function you want to execute when the script is run? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.